# Elasticsearch - searching across multiple multiple types of a index and its different types

Tags: elasticsearch

I have indexed data in elasticsearch  . Index name is "demo" .
I have two types (mappings) for "demo" , one is "user" and other is "blog".
"user" type have fields - name , city , country other fields and blog have - "title" , description" , "author_name" etc.
Now I want to search across "demo". If I want to search "java"  then it will bring all the documents which have "java" in any fields of any type , either "user" or "blog".

Comment: What solution have you tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`"_all"` field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/root-object.html#all-field) for that index. By default each of your fields will be included in the `"_all"` field for each type. Then you can just run a `match` query against the `"_all"` field. Also, when searching the index, just don't specify a type and all types will be searched.

Here is an example:

```
DELETE /test_index

PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1
   },
   "mappings": {
      "user": {
         "properties": {
             "name" : { "type": "string" },
             "city" : { "type": "string" },
             "country" : { "type": "string" }
         }
      },
      "blog": {
         "properties": {
             "title" : { "type": "string" },
             "description" : { "type": "string" },
             "author_name" : { "type": "string" }
         }
      }
   }
}

POST /test_index/_bulk
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"user"}}
{"name":"Bob","city":"New York","country":"USA"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"user"}}
{"name":"John","city":"Jakarta","country":"Java/Indonesia"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"blog"}}
{"title":"Python/ES","description":"using Python with Elasticsearch","author_name":"John"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"blog"}}
{"title":"Java/ES","description":"using Java with Elasticsearch","author_name":"Bob"}

POST /test_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
           "_all": "Java"
        }
    }
}
...
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 0.68289655,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "blog",
            "_id": "hNJ-AOG2SbS0nw4IPBuXGQ",
            "_score": 0.68289655,
            "_source": {
               "title": "Java/ES",
               "description": "using Java with Elasticsearch",
               "author_name": "Bob"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "user",
            "_id": "VqfowNx8TTG69buY9Vd_MQ",
            "_score": 0.643841,
            "_source": {
               "name": "John",
               "city": "Jakarta",
               "country": "Java/Indonesia"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```